# Linux-сервер за DNAT

Tags: iptables, debian, nat

Есть сервер в локальной сети. На нем крутится debian. На нем запущена служба, которая слушает 80 порт на 0.0.0.0 .Подключения из локальной сети и 127.0.0.1 точно работают.

Есть железный шлюз, который смотрит в Интернет. На нем прописан "Virtal Server" (он же D-NAT) на этот 80ый порт.Выдается connection timed out после задержки.

Проблема в том, что когда вместо linux-машины подставляешь win-машину - то соединение проходит (в финале пробавалась даже реальная замена IP ) ).

То есть железка пакет внутрь пробрасывает, но тот где-то застряёт уже в linux'aх.

Iptables-цепочки INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD на linux-машине - ACCEPT.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда и чем копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяйте, есть ли на Linux'е маршрут по-умолчанию. Команда `route`, ищите `default`. Он должен указывать на внутренний IP "железного" шлюза.

Или же делайте кроме D-NAT, который меняет до маршрутизации внешний IP шлюза на IP вашего сервера, еще и S-NAT, который сработает после маршрутизации, в нем заменяйте IP источника, на внутренний IP шлюза. Данный вариант плох тем, что на сервере все, что за шлюзом будет видеться как IP вашего шлюза.

Comment: Бли-ин. Шлюз 100% не туда прописан.

Comment: Дааавно я так не тупил. Спасибо!